# 7 Multiple Regressions or Multivariate Multiple Regression with 7 DVs

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

I have 7 DVs that I want to conduct the same multiple regression analysis on so I thought multivariate multiple regression (MMR) would be the way to go.  However, one of the DVs is so skewed and kurtotic that no transformation I have tried can make it both normal and non-kurtotic and when I include it in the analysis, the omnibus test of multivariate normality is significant (i.e., non-normal).

Any advice on how to proceed?  Should I report 7 multiple regressions?  Is there anything I can do to conduct the MMR with the 7 DVs?  Should I leave out the problem DV and run the MMR with 6 DVs?

Comment: We do not care about the marginal distribution of a response variable (dependent variable). When we make a normality assumption, it is about the error term or conditional distribution.

Answer (score -1):

Fit 6 predictors and observe the adjusted R^2 and then fit the model with the problematic predictor and then see how much you gain from adding the last predictor, if there is not much gain then you can ignore the last predictor and continue with the 6 predictor if they all are significant. You can also use subset selection to select the best method wrt adjusted R^2. It will give you the predictors to be include in the model for the best results.

Comment: There are seven response variables, not seven predictors.